# Webbased chat in php without using database or file

Tags: php, design-patterns, web-applications

I am trying to implement a realtime chat application using PHP . Is it possible to do it without using a persistent data storage like database or file . Basically what I need is a mediator written in PHP who

1. accepts messages from client browsers
2. Broadcasts the message to other clients
3. Forgets the message

Comment: can you build a php socket daemon?

Comment: Node.js would be ideal fit for your requirements. check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409589/node-js-multi-room-chat-example

Comment: https://github.com/kerphi/phpfreechat works great. Uses file system to store messages. Can use on any webserver/ webhost with php 5.3.0+

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will want to use `Sockets`. This article will cover exactly what you want to do: http://devzone.zend.com/209/writing-socket-servers-in-php/

Answer (score 14):

You should check out **Web Sockets** of html5. It uses two way connection so you will not need any database or file. Any chat message comes to the server will directly sent to the other users browser without any Ajax call. But you need also to setup web socket server.

Web sockets are used in many real time applications as well. I am shortly planing to write full tutorial on that. I will notify you.

Answer (score 7):

Just tried something I had never done before in response to this question. Seemed to work but I only tested it once. Instead of using a Socket I had an idea of using a shared Session variable. Basically I forced the Session_id to be the same value regardless of the user therefore they are all sharing the same data. From a quick test it seems to work. Here is what I did:

```
session_id('12345');
session_start();
$session_id = session_id();
$_SESSION['test'] = $_SESSION['test'] + 1;
echo "session: {$session_id} test: {$_SESSION['test']} <br />";
```

So my thought process was that you could simply store the chat info in a Session variable and force everyone regardless of who they are to use a shared session. Then you can simply use ajax to continually reload the current Session variable, and use ajax to edit the session variable when adding a message. Also you would probably want to set the Session to never expire or have a really long maxlifetime.

As I said I just played around with this for a few minutes to see if it would work.

Comment: OMG Never in my wildest thoughts I had this idea . Thanks for sharing this and it works! . But end of the day , the data is being stored in the file, like @stefreak said. Kudos for this exceptional thinking .

Comment: Yes it is being stored in a file. But no code is needed in order to modify / append the file. It is automatically done by the web server.

Comment: Good Technique but it will get heavy over the period of time.

Answer (score 3):

When I tried to solve the same problem, I went with Nginx's [Push Module](http://pushmodule.slact.net/). I chose to go this way since I had to support older browsers (that usually won't support WebSockets) and had no confidence in setting up an appropriate solution like [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) behind a TCP proxy.

The workflow went like this:

1. The clients connect through long-polling to my `/subscriber` location, which is open to all.
2. The `/publisher` location only accepts connections from my own server
3. When a client subscribes and talks, it basically just asks a PHP script to handle whatever data is sent.
4. This script can do validation, authorization, and such, and then forwards (via curl) the message in a JSON format to the `/publisher`.
5. Nginx's Push Module handles sending the message back to the subscribers and the client establishes a new long-polling connection.

If I had to do this all over again, then I would definitely go the Socket.io route, as it has proper fallbacks to Comet-style long-polling and has great docs for both Client and Server scripts.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a business need for PHP, then adding another language to the mix just means you then have two problems.

It is perfectly possible to run a permanent, constantly-running daemonised PHP IRCd server: I know, because I've done it, to make an online game which ran for years.

The IRC server part I used is a modified version of WaveIRCd:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/waveircd/

I daemonised it using code I made available here:
http://www.thudgame.com/node/254

That code might be overkill: I wrote it to be as rugged as I could, so it tries to daemonise using PHP's pcntl_fork(), then falls back to calling itself recursively in the background, then falls back to perl, and so on: it also handles the security restrictions of PHP's safe mode in case someone turns that on, and the security restrictions imposed by being called through cron.

You could probably strip it down to just a few lines: the bits with the comments "Daemon Rule..." - follow those rules, and you'll daemonize your process just fine.

In order to handle any unexpected daemon deaths, etc, I then ran that daemoniser every minute through cron, where it checked to see if the daemon was already running, and if so either quietly died, or if the daemon was nonresponsive, killed it and took its place.

Because of the whole distributed nature of IRC, it was nicely rugged, and gave me a multiplayer browser game with no downtime for a good few years until bit-rot ate the site a few months back. I should try to rewrite the front end in Flash and get it back up again someday, when I have time...

(I then ran another daemonizer for a PHP bot to manage the game itself, then had my game connect to it as a java applet, and talk to the bot to play the game, but that's irrelevant here).

Since WaveIRCd is no longer maintained, it's probably worth having a hunt around to find if anyone else has forked the project and is supporting it.

[2012 edit: that said, if you want your front end to be HTML5/Javascript, or if you want to connect through the same port that HTTP connects through, then your options are more limited than when using Flash or Java. In that case, take the advice of others, and use "WebSockets" (poor support in most current browsers) or the "Socket.io" project (which uses WebSockets, but falls back to Flash, or various other methods, depending what the browser has available).

The above is for situations where your host *allows* you to run a service on another port. In particular, many have explicit rules in their ToS against running an IRCd.]

[2019 edit: WebSockets are now widely supported, you should be fine using them. As a relevant case study, Slack is written in PHP (per https://slack.engineering/taking-php-seriously-cf7a60065329), and for some time supported the IRC protocol, though I believe that that has since been retired. As its main protocol, it uses an API based on JSON over WebSockets (https://api.slack.com/rtm). This all shows that a PHP IRCd can deliver enterprise-level performance and quality, even where the IRC protocol is translated to/from another one, which you'd expect to give poorer performance.]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use some kind of storage as a buffer. It IS plausable not to use file or db (which also uses a file). You can try using php's [shared memory](http://www.php.net/manual/bg/intro.shmop.php) functions, but I don't know any working solution so you'll have to do it from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to do it without using a persistent data storage like
>   database or file?

**It is possible but you shouldn't use.** Database or file based doesn't slows down chat. It will be giving additional security to your chat application. You can make web based chat using **ajax** and **sockets** without persistent data.

You should see following posts:

1. [Is database based chat room bad idea?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143458/is-database-based-chat-room-bad-idea)
2. [Will polling from a SQL DB instead of a file for chat application increase performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150174/will-polling-from-a-sql-db-instead-of-a-file-for-chat-application-increase-perfo)
3. [Using memcached as a database buffer for chat messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349617/using-memcached-as-a-database-buffer-for-chat-messages)
4. [persistent data in php question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399527/persistent-data-in-php-question)
5. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569754/how-can-i-develop-social-network-chat-without-using-a-database-for-storing-the-c
6. [File vs database for storage efficiency in chat app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314665/file-vs-database-for-storage-efficiency-in-chat-app)

Comment: You say it is possible. How is it possible to implement a chat without a persistence layer in a regular PHP setup?

Answer (score 2):

PHP is not a good fit for your requirements (in a normal setup like apache-php, fastcgi etc.), because the PHP script gets executed from top to bottom for every request and cannot maintain any state between the requests without the use of external services or databases/files (Except e.g. http://php.net/manual/de/book.apc.php, but it is not intended for implementing a chat and will not scale to multiple servers.)

You should definitely look at Node.js and especially the Node.js module Socket.IO (A Websocket library). It's incredibly easy to use and rocks. Socket.IO can also scale to multiple chat servers with an optional redis backend, which means it's easier to scale.

Trying to use `$_SESSION` with a static session id as communication channel is not a solution by the way, because PHP saves the session data into files.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to achieving this is by writing a PHP socket server.

```
<?php

// Set time limit to indefinite execution

set_time_limit (0);

// Set the ip and port we will listen on

$address = '192.168.0.100';

$port = 9000;

$max_clients = 10;

// Array that will hold client information

$clients = Array();

// Create a TCP Stream socket

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

// Bind the socket to an address/port

socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) or die('Could not bind to address');

// Start listening for connections

socket_listen($sock);

// Loop continuously

while (true) {

    // Setup clients listen socket for reading

    $read[0] = $sock;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $max_clients; $i++)

    {

        if ($client[$i]['sock']  != null)

            $read[$i + 1] = $client[$i]['sock'] ;

    }

    // Set up a blocking call to socket_select()

    $ready = socket_select($read,null,null,null);

    /* if a new connection is being made add it to the client array */

    if (in_array($sock, $read)) {

        for ($i = 0; $i < $max_clients; $i++)

        {

            if ($client[$i]['sock'] == null) {

                $client[$i]['sock'] = socket_accept($sock);

                break;

            }

            elseif ($i == $max_clients - 1)

                print ("too many clients")

        }

        if (--$ready <= 0)

            continue;

    } // end if in_array



    // If a client is trying to write - handle it now

    for ($i = 0; $i < $max_clients; $i++) // for each client

    {

        if (in_array($client[$i]['sock'] , $read))

        {

            $input = socket_read($client[$i]['sock'] , 1024);

            if ($input == null) {

                // Zero length string meaning disconnected

                unset($client[$i]);

            }

            $n = trim($input);

            if ($input == 'exit') {

                // requested disconnect

                socket_close($client[$i]['sock']);

            } elseif ($input) {

                // strip white spaces and write back to user

                $output = ereg_replace("[ \t\n\r]","",$input).chr(0);

                socket_write($client[$i]['sock'],$output);

            }

        } else {

            // Close the socket

            socket_close($client[$i]['sock']);

            unset($client[$i]);

        }

    }

} // end while

// Close the master sockets

socket_close($sock);

?>
```

You would execute this by running it through command line and would always have to run for your PHP clients to connect to it. You could then write a PHP client that would connect to the socket.

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

You would have to use some type of ajax to call with jQuery posting the message to this PHP client.

http://devzone.zend.com/209/writing-socket-servers-in-php/
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

Answer (score 1):

Better use a node.js server for this. WebSockets aren't cross-browser nowadays (except socket.io for node.js that works perfect)

Answer (score 0):

in short answer, you can't.
the current HTTP/HTML implementation doesn't support the `pushstate` so the algorithm of your chat app should follow :

1. A: sent message
2. B,C,D: do while a new message has been sent  get this message.

so the receivers always have to make a new request and check if a new message has been sent. (AJAX Call or something similar )
so always there are a delay between the sent event and the receive event.

- which means the data must be saved in something global, like db or file system.

take a look for :
http://today.java.net/article/2010/03/31/html5-server-push-technologies-part-1

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say it had to *all* be written it PHP :)

Install RabbitMQ, and then use this chat implementation built on top of websockets and RabbitMQ.

Your PHP is pretty much just 'chat room chrome'.  It's possible most of your site would fit within the 5 meg limit of offline HTML5 content, and you have a very flexible (and likely more robust than if you did it yourself) chat system.

It even has 20 messages of chat history if you leave the room.

https://github.com/videlalvaro/rabbitmq-chat

Answer (score -1):

If You need to use just PHP, then You can store chat messages in session variables, session could be like object, storing a lot of information.
If You can use jQuery then You could just append paragraph to a div after message has been sent, but then if site is refreshed, messages will be gone.
Or combining, store messages in session and update that with jQuery and ajax.

Comment: Thanks . But how do I get messages between sessions . Each user will be in different sessions

Comment: Hmm, indeed I didn't though about that. I will think a bit, and then edit my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try looking into socket libraries like [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) they allow for instant transport of the message, and are quicker than TCP, and is realtime. Their infrastructure allows for instant data send between points A and B, without the data being stored anywhere first (although you can still choose to).
Here's a [tutorial for a chat client in ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/code%3aexamples-chat)

Comment: `and are quicker than TCP` is not true. Quote from their website: `Faster than TCP, **for clustered products and supercomputing.**`. Other than that, for this chat, they would use TCP (which is not faster than TCP): `Carries messages across inproc, IPC, TCP, and multicast.`.